# How to run an asp.net application in local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I am kind of new to asp.net.

I have created an application using Visual studio 2013 Web Express and MVC5. When I wanted to run the application, I was pressing the run button from VS and it managed to open it.

Now I switched the server from `IIS Express` to `Local IIS`. When I run the application in the browser, it gives me

```
Server Error in '/' Application. <br>
Access is denied. 

Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18446
```

I guess because I don't have like `Default.aspx` file or something, I don't know what is the problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working.

The problem was, I am using windows authentication to access the web application (VS asked me when the project first created). Now I didn't know I need to set it in the iis too.

All I did is enabling the `Windows Authentication` in iis > MySite > Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue. When you develop and run an application inside visual studio it has all the rights it needs. So you need to configure iis when wanting to demo/use the site directly from the webserver. After you have made the application inside IIS -> select the application and in the Actions pane you should see the link 'Edit Permissions'. Clicking that brings up the properties tab and under security add your account or an administrator account and elevate the rights until the site works.

Comment: I gave full access to my account and other users and still not working.